# Make apachebench(ab) send HTTP1.1 request?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, testing

I'm trying to use `ab` to test my webserver, but it only supports HTTP/1.1 (reject requests that have HTTP/1.0 in the first line). The `-k` switch only adds a header with `connection: keep-alive`.

Is it possible to make `ab` send HTTP/1.1 request?

Comment: Why are you rejecting 1.0 requests?  Be careful with that if this is to be publicly accessible; you'll break clients coming through some proxy servers.

Comment: You have two choices: modify `ab` to support HTTP 1.1, or modify your web server to support HTTP 1.0. (You can probably get away with just modify `ab` send send HTTP/1.1, but that's not ideal.)

Comment: Do you mean that ab _does not_ support HTTP/1.1? The question as written doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about using Siege, it is as easy to use as ab, but it supports HTTP/1.1:

http://www.joedog.org/index/siege-home

Answer (score 3):

A way found in [CMU's 15-441](https://github.com/computer-networks/liso-starter-code/blob/b92be13efb5a5aefbab129cf0325eb5256fa9734/DockerFile#L7):

```
perl -pi -e 's/HTTP\/1.0/HTTP\/1.1/g' /usr/bin/ab
```

Hacky, but it works! :D

Comment: A warning: This will modify the executable `/usr/bin/ab`! This must be run as root, it might trigger intrusion detection systems, and it must be repeated after every update of the package `apache2-utils`!

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Of course it has lots of drawbacks. It comes from the official code in CMU's course, so I share it here (9 years after the question :) )

Comment: This is beautiful.  Here's my version, which has less requirements and doesn't modify the original binary:  `sed 's|HTTP/1.0|HTTP/1.1|g' /usr/bin/ab >ab-http11`